# Having issue with authclient in Yii2

Tags: php, yii2

I integrated social authentication based on this tutorial:

http://stuff.cebe.cc/yii2docs/guide-security-auth-clients.html

Here is my configuration file:

```
'authClientCollection' => [
    'class' => 'yii\authclient\Collection',
    'clients' => [
        'facebook' => [
            'class' => 'yii\authclient\clients\Facebook',
            'clientId' => 'my_id',
            'clientSecret' => 'my_secret',
        ],
        'linkedin' => [
            'class' => 'yii\authclient\clients\LinkedIn',
            'clientId' => 'my_id',
            'clientSecret' => 'my_secret',
        ],
    ],
],
```

My problem is,  when I click on social buttons it redirects into login page. I tried even something like that:

```
   public function onAuthSuccess($client) {
      $attributes = $client->getUserAttributes();
        die(print_r($attributes));
        ...
```

Even this doesn't work for me, it just 302 redirects into login page.

What might be issue?

Answer (score 2):

Maybe you are getting *access_denied* error ? because by default when *get* request from OAuth server contain *error* parameter and if it is equal to *access_denied*, the *AuthAction* redirects user to *cancelUrl* which is by default is *loginUrl*.

Try to set `'cancelUrl' => Url::to(['site/login', $_GET])` in *auth* action configuration, and check `$_GET` parameters from OAuth server in url after redirect

Also redirect to *cancelUrl* happens if *OAuthClient* cannot fetch   *AccessToken*